# Dreamweaver - File ( FTP ) Activity every time I open or save a file? Why?

Tags: ftp, dreamweaver

I'm running Adobe CS6 Dreamweaver for a number of different sites, and I'm running into one particular site ( that I recently created from a clone of another, strangely ) that is acting a little... Odd.

Every time I open or save a file, it performs Some sort of file operation that halts my ability to immediately upload my changes, for instance. The FTP dialog box opens, it does something very quickly ( so much so that I never get to see what it is doing ), and closes - only to reopen again for a moment and perform what appears to be the same task.

Now, I've been through most of the settings in the site's configuration, and I don't see anything jumping out at me - and to head the question off at the pass; 'Upload on Save' is disabled.

[ETA]: I have also ensured that I am using my 'Local View' to open and save files from. Just to get the silly things out of the way.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

NAILED it.

Alright, so if 'Discover Dynamically-Related Files' is on and you have a testing server established, this action will persist.

To disable it:

```
Edit -> Preferences
    General
        [Switch] 'Discover Dynamically-Related Files' to 'Manually' or 'Disabled'
```

Cheers.